# how to send a http post request to server in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, timestamp, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

how do i send device token from my native iphone app with a specific timer request so that after the specified time push notification alert comes to device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question and the text of it don't exactly match.

The easiest way to set up a timer request for push is to sign up with a push service provider that offers timed requests (UrbanAirship does but you may also want to check others like iLime or push.io).

The other option is to write a server where you can queue the requests then run a cron job to push them out. Obviously, that'll take more work. To actually post the message, you could use something like ASIHTTPRequest.

You may also want to tell your users not to rely on exact timing. A lot of variables enter into the process especially if user is on WiFi.

Comment: you mean i need to implement those methods by myself..can you tell me the required methods or a sample piece of code so that my question can be easily understandable

Comment: Writing the server is a pretty complex operation. I wouldn't recommend it if you haven't done it. You may want to start with UrbanAirship. They provide sample code for talking to their service in Objective-C that shows exactly what to do and implements the ASIHTTPRequest calls to do push through their service.

Comment: but i want to implement my own server.cause urabnairship charges